# class name not found in middleware method - Laravel 5

Tags: php, class, laravel, middleware, laravel-5

I am trying to set up middleware. 
I followed these instructions:

http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style

And my code is

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class LoadVars {

$comingevents = App\Number::where('item','events')->get(array('quantity'));
```

I got this error:

FatalErrorException in LoadVars.php line 24:
Class 'App\Http\Middleware\App\Number' not found

In models when I define relations I use **App\Number** and it works well.

What is the proper way of using Classes inside a middleware method?

Comment: You have specify the absolute namespace by prefixing it with a backslash: `\App\Number`, otherwise it will be interpreted relative to the namespace you are currently in, which is `App\Http\Middleware`. Or you could `use App\Number;` at the top and then just access it with `Number::where(...);`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It helped me to get orientation in the new L5 namespace rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Quasdunk pointed out right in the comments, when you reference a class without backslash at the beginning, the path is **relative**.
Meaning `App\Number` will look in the current namespace for `App` and then `Number`.

```
App\Http\Middleware  &  App\Number   =>  App\Http\Middleware\App\Number
```

You just have to add a `\` at the start and the path will be interpreted **absolute** and it actually doesn't matter *from where* you are using the class

```
App\Http\Middleware  &  \App\Number  =>  App\Number
Foo\Bar              &  \App\Number  =>  App\Number
```

If you like your code a bit cleaner you can also import the class with a `use` statement:

```
use App\Number;

class LoadVars {
    // ...
    $comingevents = Number::where('item','events')->get(array('quantity'));
    // ...
}
```

**Note** that with the `use` statement there's no need for the backslash. All paths will be absolute.

Comment: Yup, @Quasdung pushed me in the right direction and later I learned to declare classes at the head of Controllers.

Many thanks to both of you!